# Which are your asp.net C# debugging wrappers

Tags: c#, asp.net

Did not receive any exact answer, thus I would have to accept mine ... See code bellow

Comment: You seem to be passing an awful lot of things by reference pointlessly. I suggest you read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html - I suspect you may not understand what "ref" means.

Comment: The code would work a lot better here is you changed the indentation to 2 spaces and removed many of the commented out statements. Also learn that control-] matches braces, no need to comment closing braces (as well as being highlighted).

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

I quess I should remove the ref from the echoable objects ... I would like to preserve it for the userObj , since it holds objects, which would be populated during debugging for further usage ...

Comment: **** The code would work a lot better here is you changed the indentation to 2 spaces Richard , I have in my VS settings 1 \t = 2 spaces. It really looks much better in VS...

Comment: *** Also learn that control-] matches braces, no need to comment closing braces (as well as being highlighted)

In my FI keyboard is Ctrl + å --- the reason to have //eof method is that I am really blind for this type of errors , no colouring even works for me ...

Comment: Commenting closing brackets can be good documentation practice so please do not tell people not to do it. As with anything you have to use it rationally. Also DO NOT INDENT 2 SPACES! INDENT 4 SPACES!!! 2 spaces is too hard to read.  So as you see it's all opinion. Code how you like but be smart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;

namespace YourDebug.Name.Space
{

/// <summary>
///Debugs passed objects and returns ready formatted html with the objects values
/// </summary>
public class HtmlDebugger
{
    public static string DumpDataSet(string msg, DataSet ds)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<p> START " + msg + "</p>");
        if (ds == null)
            return msg + " null ds passed ";

        if (ds.Tables == null || ds.Tables.Count == 0)
            return msg + " no tables in ds ";

            sb.Append("<p> DEBUG START --- " + msg + "</p>");            
            foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                sb.Append("================= My TableName is  " +
                dt.TableName + " ========================= START");
                sb.Append("<table>\n");
                int colNumberInRow = 0;
                foreach (System.Data.DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sb.Append(" <th>  ");
                    sb.Append(" |" + colNumberInRow + "| ");
                    sb.Append(dc.ColumnName + " </th> ");
                    colNumberInRow++;
                } //eof foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                int rowNum = 0;
                foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string strBackGround = String.Empty;
                    if (rowNum% 2 == 0)
                        strBackGround = " bgcolor=\"#D2D2D2\" "; 



                    sb.Append("\n " + rowNum + "<tr " + strBackGround + " >");
                    int colNumber = 0;
                    foreach (System.Data.DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        sb.Append("<td> |" + colNumber + "| ");
                        sb.Append(dr[dc].ToString() + " </td>");
                        colNumber++;
                    } //eof foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                    rowNum++;
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                }    //eof foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                sb.Append(" \n");
                sb.Append("</table>");
            }    //eof foreach (DataTable dt in sb.Append.Tables)
            sb.Append("<p> DEBUG END--- " + msg + "</p>");            

            return sb.ToString();

    }//eof method  


    public static string DumpMsgList(string msg, 
    System.Collections.Generic.List<GenApp.Dh.Msg> listMsgs)
    {

        System.Text.StringBuilder echo = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (listMsgs == null)
            return "null listMsgs passed for debugging ";

        if (listMsgs.Count == 0)
            return "listMsgs.Count == 0"; 



        echo.Append("<table>");
        for (int msgCounter = 0; msgCounter < listMsgs.Count; msgCounter++)
        {
            GenApp.Dh.Msg objMsg = listMsgs[msgCounter];
            string strBackGround = String.Empty;
            if (msgCounter % 2 == 0)
                strBackGround = " bgcolor=\"#D2D2D2\" "; 

            echo.Append("<tr" + strBackGround + ">");
            echo.Append("<td>msg.MsgKey</td> <td> " + objMsg.MsgKey + "</td>");
            echo.Append("<td>msg.MsgId</td><td>" + objMsg.MsgId + "</td>");
            echo.Append("</tr>");
        } //eof foreach 
        echo.Append("</table>");
        return echo.ToString();


    } //eof method 

    public static string DumpIDataReader(string msg, IDataReader rdr)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (rdr == null)
            return " <p> IDataReader rds is null </p>";


            sb.Append("DEBUG START ---" + msg);
            sb.Append("<table>");
            int counter = 0; 
            while (rdr.Read() )
            {
                string strBackGround = String.Empty;
                if (counter % 2 == 0)
                    strBackGround = " bgcolor=\"#3EBDE8\" "; 

                sb.Append("<tr" + strBackGround + ">");
                for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                    sb.Append(rdr[i].ToString() + " ");
                    sb.Append("<td>");
                } //eof for 
                sb.Append("</br>");
                sb.Append("</tr>");
                counter++; 
            }
            sb.Append("<table>");
            sb.Append("DEBUG END ---" + msg);


            return sb.ToString();        
    } //eof method 


    public static string DumpListDictionary(string msg , 
    ListDictionary list)
    {
      if (list == null)
        return "<p> null list passed </p>";

      if (list.Count == 0)
        return "<p> list.Count = 0 </p> "; 


          System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

          sb.Append("<p> START DUMP " + msg + " </p>");
          sb.Append("<table>");

          int counter = 0; 
          foreach (object key in list.Keys)
          {
            string strBackGround = String.Empty;
            if (counter % 2 == 0)
              strBackGround = " bgcolor=\"#D2D2D2\" ";

            sb.Append("<tr" + strBackGround + "><td> key - </td><td> " + 
            key.ToString());
            sb.Append("</td><td>===</td><td>value - </td><td> " + list[key] + 
            "</td></br></tr>");
            counter++;
          } //eof foreach 

          sb.Append("</table>");
          sb.Append("<p> END DUMP " + msg + " </p>");
      return sb.ToString();
    } //eof method 

} //eof class
```

} //eof namespace

Answer (score 0):

I just hoped somebody would also suggest other options for example [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/download.html)